# How can I style code listings using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to display snippets of programming language code, and also HTML code, inside an HTML document using CSS. I want it to be indented and in fixed-width font... I'm thinking of something like:

```
<blockquote style="some_style">
my code here
my code here also
</blockquote>
```

and have it appear in a nicely formatted way (bonus if it's color coded, but doesn't have to be.

How can I accomplish this using CSS?

Comment: Color-coding will require one of the various syntax highlighters available.. The are pure-JavaScript solutions if you don't have access to PHP.

Answer (score 126):

Sharing an example I use in website, I do use following `pre` in my stylesheet:

```
pre {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 3px solid #f36d33;
    color: #666;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This gives the following results:

[image]

> **Disclaimer:** In my leisure time, I have spend few hours to update this CSS with a bit extra features like code lines and code Copy button using CSS with JavaScript to my personal use that I like to share. Please use as you like [github](https://github.com/maythamfahmi/codestyler) source code. To see a code example in real world, check this [article](https://itbackyard.com/how-to-make-shortest-path-in-grid-using-bfs-in-c/) from my blog that show how I use the code sample.

Comment: Do you mind sharing HTML code snippet where actual code is present ?

Comment: @BeingSuman no I do not mind, just I understand you correctly, you are looking for full code example for the above example, if Yes, let me know so I can do it later I am home. otherwise if you look at the git repo there are some examples you can look at let me know as well if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, got sample by inspecting the element on your website.

Comment: Nice design, but it's not responsive.

Comment: @JivkoJelev when time allow I will make it responsive :)

Comment: Looks like `page-break-inside` is now `break-inside` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: Also, since this styling is specific to code, and not to all preformatted text, would it be semantically better to apply it to `<code>` and not `<pre>`?

Answer (score 53):

This javascript library seems excellent:

https://highlightjs.org/

UPDATE: I also used this on my Tumblr-based blog because it was easiest to deploy:

https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Answer (score 25):

`<pre>` would automatically retain your tabs and line-breaks within the bounding `pre` tags. Most browsers automatically default to a monospaced font inside `pre` but if you want to force it, (which is a good idea) you can use the following CSS:

```
pre { font-family: monospace; }
```

I would recommend that you *not* place code directly into a `<blockquote>` element. It is semantically incorrect.

If you want your code to be semantically correct, you should mark it up like this:

```
<pre><code>
My pre-formatted code
    here.
</code></pre>
```

If you are actually "quoting" a block of code, then the markup would be:

```
<blockquote><pre><code>
My pre-formatted "quoted" code here.
</code></pre></blockquote>
```

If you want even better-looking code, you can employ Google Code's [Prettify](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify) which is [used by StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33256/stackoverflows-code-color-coding-script-available) to color code-snippets. It has it's own stylesheets that it automatically imports based on what language it thinks the code is and colors the code accordingly. You can give it a hint as to what language the code is by [appending a class](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify#how-do-i-specify-the-language-of-my-code).

Comment: (fyi) <pre> tags are no longer supported in Tumblr.

Answer (score 12):

Well, you could try using a <pre> tag in your blockquote to preserve the formatting first, and then use a monospaced font, like courier for the css style.

Something like this would work in the css:

```
pre {
  font-family:     "Courier New"
                    Courier
                    monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can take a look at the [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/) to highlight the code.

You can customise the package as your wish from [here](http://prismjs.com/download.html) and the footprint of this package will be still minimal.

Once you have a package, then you can use it as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <link href="themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="prism.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Once the above setup is done, then you can use it like below:

```
<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

First, I would show the code in a `<pre> </pre>` element give the pre element a nice style in your css and call it a day.