# Format <p> tags in Angular in desired way

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I was working on a personal project where, I came across a situation where I have to take a large text input from user [Kind of like a reddit post or stackoverflow post].

I found out that by default

tags do not preserve line breaks.
I solved this issue by using css [white-space: pre;]
[Thanks to this post :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

But what i need is to format the user entered text in a certain way , such that it would fit into a mat-card and also will be able to format code like ``` tags in stackOverflow.

```html
<div class="zorroWrap">
  <nz-card style="width:410px;" nzTitle="{{ article.title }}" [nzExtra]="extraTemplate" [nzActions]="[actionEllipsis , voteDisplay]">
    <div class="angular-with-newlines">
      <p align="justify">{{ article.desc }}</p>
    </div>
  </nz-card>
  <ng-template #extraTemplate>
    <a href="#">More</a>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #actionEllipsis>
    <i nz-icon nzType="ellipsis"></i>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #voteDisplay>
    <i nz-icon [nzType]="'heart'" (click)="upVoteArticle()" [nzTheme]="'twotone'" [nzTwotoneColor]="'#eb2f96'"></i>
    <i nz-icon nzType="ellipsis">&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ article.votes }}</i>
  </ng-template>
  <div>
```

I am using ng-zorro.

I need the `<p>` tag's text formatted with preserved new lines [also an option to format code maybe like ``` or something] and the entire text should stay inside the card [should not overflow (I know i can do this using css, but would love to know if there is any better way)]

Thank You!

Edit:

Using css preserve's the new lines, as below:
[image]

I also found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000792/how-can-i-style-code-listings-using-css) , which had sources of external libraries to pre format.

Any other Angular way? (which is maybe better)

Comment: Why not use CSS?

Comment: How the content of 'article.desc' is formatted ? Have you the input to show us ?